# Http Get on javascript file on IE11 takes long time

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-11

using IE11 the time taken to load the javascript and png files is very huge. After disabling addons it was faster but still not as expected. Javascript loading is happening at the begining of the page and this is causing delay in page loading. Does this have anything to do with network?

[image: Network information from IE11]

Comment: You mention IE explicitly, yet you ask about network. Did you test with other browsers? Is this site public, so we can test it?

Comment: I observed this with IE. I tested with chrome, but there is an addon which works only on IE and the user wants it by all means. Unfortunately the site is not public. Same Web application deployed on a server within the company - it takes 250ms to 3s to load the files

Comment: So without that addon it does work fast? And in Chrome as well? Which addon is it? Please provide that context. Without those (and other) details nobody would be able to provide a good answer.

Comment: I disabled several addons - Cisco Webex, Avaya - Call Taking. And without addons it was faster - it took about 6sec - 9sec. As a result overall page load time is slower. Please let me know if you need additional details. I was more inclined to understand why javascript loads would be slow.